# how to get the last record from foreign key

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Hi I'm a newbie with spring data jpa. I'm doing JPA rest end point with mysql. I need some guidance on how to I proceed with this issue. Let's assume that I have 2 entities like this:

Product

```
@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String productName;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "product")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Price> priceList;

}
```

And I have price entity:

```
@Entity
public class Price {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private LocalDateTime priceDate;
    private BigDecimal price;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="product_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Product product;
}
```

If i do a normal query is fine and it has no problem, it will give me results like this:

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "productName": "product_foo"
   "price": [
   {
      "id":1
      "priceDate": "12-9-2018",
      "price":500
    },
    {
      "id":2
      "priceDate": "12-19-2018",
      "price":510
    },
    {
      "id":3
      "priceDate": "12-22-2018",
      "price":512
    }
    ]
}
```

But, What i'm trying to achieve is :

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "productName": "product_foo"
   "price": [
    {
      "id":3
      "priceDate": "12-22-2018",
      "price":512
    }
    ]
}
```

In short, I just want to fetch the last price in the table and slap it into the price list. how do I achieve this?

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no way to limit collections association size in hibernate.

We can use @Where, @Filter annotation to filter records but we can not limit them.

You can get the latest price object by mapping it to attribute as below, [kind of hack], and then use this to populate price list with some additional logic.

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinFormula(value = "(SELECT price.id FROM price WHERE price.product_id = id ORDER BY price.id DESC LIMIT 1)")
private Price latestPrice;
```

Here it **id** in where clause refers to id of product.

But again, this is not an elegant way to achieve this and discouraged.
So, you should consider using,

- HQL/JPQL
- Criteria API
- Native SQL
  to, get latest price by ordering and limit using setMaxResult().